# ROS: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' when running from roslaunch

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I'm trying to run an example from openCv python examples which is [mosse.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/mosse.py).

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo and OpenCV 3 with Pyhon 2.7.

When I run the example from `rosrun` like

```
rosrun ucf_ardrone mosse.py
```

it ran successfully as I want to check that I brought all the required libraries, but when I run it from launch file it shows an error:

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[mosse-1]: started with pid [27040]
GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "__name"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saif/catkin_ws/src/ucf_ardrone/scripts/mosse.py", line 198, in <module>
    App(video_src, paused = '--pause' in opts).run()
  File "/home/saif/catkin_ws/src/ucf_ardrone/scripts/mosse.py", line 150, in __init__
    _, self.frame = self.cap.read()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
================================================================================REQUIRED process [mosse-1] has died!
process has died [pid 27040, exit code 1, cmd /home/saif/catkin_ws/src/ucf_ardrone/scripts/mosse.py __name:=mosse __log:=/home/saif/.ros/log/065b2628-f914-11e6-89bf-3c970e1c0b5b/mosse-1.log].
log file: /home/saif/.ros/log/065b2628-f914-11e6-89bf-3c970e1c0b5b/mosse-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[mosse-1] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

This is the launch file

```
<launch>
    <!-- <node name="hello" pkg="ucf_ardrone" type="hello.py" output="screen" required="true" /> -->
    <node name="mosse" pkg="ucf_ardrone" type="mosse.py" required="true" />
</launch>
```

I'm still learning ROS environment so any hint will be great!

Thanks,

Comment: Is this `mosse.py` depending on the directory from which it is called? While `rosrun` runs it in your current working directory, `roslauch` will always run it in `~/.ros`. That is the only relevant difference I can currently think of.